# In psql how to run a Loop for a Select query with CTEs and get the output shown in read-only db?

Tags: postgresql, loops

EDIT: I am creating a new question as per suggestion from sticky bit.

I have a query with CTEs to output results for several values (1 to 12). Below is a simplified example. Running it I got the following error:

ERROR:  query has no destination for result data

HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 8 at SQL statement

I can't output the result of Select in a table. How can I solve this problem?

```
DO $$
DECLARE r integer;
BEGIN
    r := 1;
    WHILE r <= 2 
    LOOP
        r := r + 1;
        WITH params AS (
            SELECT r AS rownumber 
        ),
        time AS (
            SELECT id
                FROM params, analysis
                ORDER BY date DESC
                LIMIT 1 
                OFFSET (SELECT rownumber - 1 from params) 
        )

        SELECT * FROM time;
    END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

Comment: An anonymous function(`DO`) can't return anything, so there is nothing you can do in this function to change that. Turn it into a regular function and take a look here [Return from function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) 42.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY

Comment: Just caught the read-only part of title. I'm guessing you can't do `CREATE FUNCTION` then?  Your only choice then would be to use the `DO` function and `DECLARE` an `int` variable(`int_var int;`) then `select into int_var * from time` and then `RAISE NOTICE 'id: %', int_var;`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I am not much familiar with functions and other things you mentioned, but I have only read only access to db.

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). [Edit] the question (or delete this and ask a new one) and tell us what you **actually** want to do. Include a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables involved and `INSERT` statements with some sample data for them. Only paste the text of the statements, do **not** use images. Add the desired result with that sample data in tabular text form.

Comment: i don't see the need for a loop. it looks like you could achieve what you want using `generate_series()`.

Comment: @stickybit, I added new question instead of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65444104/in-psql-how-to-run-a-loop-for-a-select-query-with-ctes-and-get-the-output-shown

Comment: @eRic: OK, great! But don't forget to delete this one.

Comment: @stickybit, I am thinking that the answer by Adrian Klaver is an answer to my badly formulated question here. And also when I tried to delete it I was not recommended to do that by the system. I will accept this answer, as in a terminal it outputs what is needed, but in the GUI app it shows something like the status of query run, while the result is shown as a warning. I will rather keep both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of what I mentioned in my comment:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
   r integer;
   int_var integer;
BEGIN
    r := 1;
    WHILE r <= 12 LOOP
        WITH params AS (
            SELECT r AS rownumber 
        ),
        time AS (
            SELECT id
                FROM params, analysis
                ORDER BY date DESC
                LIMIT 1 
                OFFSET (SELECT rownumber - 1 from params) 
        )

        SELECT INTO int_var id FROM time;
        RAISE NOTICE 'id: %', int_var; 
        r := r + 1;
    END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

You can't `RETURN` a value from a `DO` function, but you can `RAISE NOTICE` a value as above. The `SELECT INTO` will eliminate the error as you are giving the `SELECT` a destination(the `int_var`) for its output. **NOTE**: `SELECT INTO` inside `plpgsql` is different then the same command outside. Outside it is equivalent to `CREATE TABLE AS`.